# When I access Jenkins trough an EC2 I get an error

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, jenkins-cli

I got an issue. I created a Jenkins AMI that i snapshoted it and created an image from a running ec2 instance with an already configured Jenkins Master on port 8443 with an https certificate. But when I curl to the jenkins instance i get the following:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2tz0.png

I checked Jenkins logs and everything was normal. And my Elatic Load balancer is healthy which means the security groups and other things are working just fine. Does anybody have a clue why is it giving a 403 Forbidden? Another point is that I can even access the GUI

Comment: As per the screenshot, it says you are logged in "anonymous" hence the forbidden error. What is that exactly you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

By using `curl` you're making your life harder but look at some of what comes back:

```
<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=/login?from=%2F'/>
```

If you've done HTML programming, this is one way of having the browser execute a redirect.  Why Jenkins doesn't do some sort of HTTP redirect I don't know but the code is telling you that, after 1 second, redirect to the url `/login`.

`curl` isn't going to interpret the HTML for you, unlike the browser.  Jenkins is working fine - you just need to follow what the HTML and JavaScript code is telling you to do through curl.

Comment: I'm not sure what you tried but can I ask what it is you're trying to do?  Why `curl`?  If you need to access something within Jenkins there is [an extensive API](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/remote-access-api/) but you'll need to get the token via the GUI first.

Comment: My mistake. I actually worked. The issue now its that its not reflecting on the vpcendpoint. It works directly inside the machine but does not reflect. Thank you @stdunbar. Now Imma gonna try to troubleshoot the vpc endpoint

Comment: And just a heads up if your using elastic load balancer with an https always use the target group as TCP and TLS, TLS remains in the listner and not the target group

Answer (score 0):

The 403 error is the Jenkins application specifically saying your current user is not allowed access to the current action.

It appears you’re not logged in so your action is treated as an anonymous user. If the anonymous user should have the permissions to access this action you will need to add them.